# IR not working on Pi 4 - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: pi-4, lirc

I've sunk about a week into trying to receive infrared on RPi v4. I've worked through the LIRC docs and a number of tutorials.

I am using the VS1838 IR receiver. I actually have 2 which I've been using to make sure that the fault is not with the receiver itself.

My wiring seems to be correct and I've verified that by connecting other devices with the same breadboard/wiring. I have data sent to GPIO 18, power to 3.3V, and ground to ground. I also experimented with temporarily higher voltage.

LIRC is installed. I've tried turning the service on, off, restarting it, rebooting, etc.

`sudo ir-keytable -c -p all -t` never detects any events. I have verified that the remote is working and have tried 2 alternate remotes. `mode2 -m -d /dev/lirc0` also returns nothing.

In my `/boot/config.txt` I have:

```
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=18
```

with help from Dmitry's answer below I ran `modinfo` on the driver which shows me this:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.63-v7l+/kernel/drivers/media/rc/gpio-ir-recv.ko
license:        GPL v2
description:    GPIO IR Receiver driver
srcversion:     5DDEB234BED17634DA37C0C
alias:          of:N*T*Cgpio-ir-receiverC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cgpio-ir-receiver
depends:
intree:         Y
name:           gpio_ir_recv
vermagic:       5.10.63-v7l+ SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by checking that `/dev/lirc0` is actually working. Look up its major/minor numbers with `ls -l /dev/lirc0` and then do a

```
readlink /sys/dev/char/<X>\:<Y>/device/driver
```

where `<X>` and `<Y>` are the numbers given by `ls`. That should tell you which driver is associated with that device (`gpio-ir-recv`?). You can then check if the driver is loaded and how it is configured using `lsmod`, `modinfo <driver-name>` etc.

Comment: `ls /sys/dev/char/251\:0/device` returns `device  input2  lirc0  power  protocols  subsystem  uevent`......  OK here we go... `ls /sys/dev/char/251\:0/device/device/driver` returns
`bind  ir-receiver@12  module  uevent  unbind`. So the driver is `ir-receiver@12`?  I tried `modinfo` but it says `modinfo: ERROR: Module ir-receiver@12 not found.`

Comment: OK so if I do `ls -l` on the driver it says `../../../bus/platform/drivers/gpio_ir_recv`. Then `modinfo` gives me `filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.63-v7l+/kernel/drivers/media/rc/gpio-ir-recv.ko
license:        GPL v2
description:    GPIO IR Receiver driver
srcversion:     5DDEB234BED17634DA37C0C
alias:          of:N*T*Cgpio-ir-receiverC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cgpio-ir-receiver
depends:
intree:         Y
name:           gpio_ir_recv
vermagic:       5.10.63-v7l+ SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8`

Answer (score 0):

You have not asked a question.

[piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) will show if the VS1838 is working properly.

Depending on your needs [IR Record and Playback](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py) may work.

Comment: Thanks. I added "how to troubleshoot?" to my question to make it more explicit.